# SQL ignore all blank fields in calculation

Tags: sql

I am using the following query in SQL within PhpRunner:

```
SELECT
[Date],
(MondayStrengthEnd1Sets*MondayStrengthEnd1Reps*MondayStrengthEnd1Distance) + (MondayStrengthEnd2Sets*MondayStrengthEnd2Reps*MondayStrengthEnd2Distance) AS Total
FROM Running
```

When I run the query I get a blank for an answer. Some of the fields will not necessarily be filled in for every record. The example above is just a snippet of all the fields that is in the table and in the complete calculation, there will be almost 90 fields in total. All the fields are from the same table.

What can I add to the query to treat the blank fields as blanks and not as zeros in order to still calculate the total despite some fields not being filled in? If there is anything that will do it automatically for all the fields it would be great.

I am aiming for something like this:
[image]

Comment: Blank fields? You mean NULL columns?

Comment: The whole columns will not necessarily be NULL, some records may have a field filled in where the next record for that same column might not be filled in

Comment: Add _some_ sample table data, and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: @jarlh I have edited the original question with a picture of what I am aiming for

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need something like:

```
SELECT
    [Date],
   isnull(MondayStrengthEnd1Sets*MondayStrengthEnd1Reps*MondayStrengthEnd1Distance, 0) 
   + isnull(MondayStrengthEnd2Sets*MondayStrengthEnd2Reps*MondayStrengthEnd2Distance, 0) 
     AS Total
FROM Running
```

Comment: Note that ISNULL() is a product specific function. I'd recommend COALESCE() instead.